# Xcode with uncrustify: how to align function declaration to colons?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uncrustify

I have the following **code**:

```
@interface TRYoutubeManager : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

- (void)getVideosForDefaultChannelsWithSuccess:(void (^)(NSArray *youtubeVideosArray))successBlock failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failureBlock;

@end
```

So **I want** to preserve 120 characters line limit. And align declaration on colons, like this:

```
@interface TRYoutubeManager : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

- (void)getVideosForDefaultChannelsWithSuccess:(void (^)(NSArray *youtubeVideosArray))successBlock
                                       failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failureBlock;

@end
```

But when I apply Uncrustify on it, **I get**:

```
@interface TRYoutubeManager : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

- (void)getVideosForDefaultChannelsWithSuccess:(void (^)(NSArray *youtubeVideosArray))successBlock failure:(void (^)(
                                                                                                                     NSError *
                                                                                                                     error))
failureBlock;

@end
```

Plugin spoils the whole thing. Even line limit exceeded.
Here it is **some critical** (I guess) params:

```
# Align ObjC declaration params on colon
align_oc_decl_colon                     = true          # 
# Alignment span for ObjC message colons
align_oc_msg_colon_span                 = 20            # number

# Alignment span for ObjC message spec
align_oc_msg_spec_span                  = 0             # number
# Code width
code_width                              = 120           # number
```

The whole config file [HERE](https://yadi.sk/d/19LFm-Nobfw4D)

Please, help me to setup Uncrustify config correclty.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking into those:

```
nl_oc_msg_leave_one_liner                 { False, True }   Don't
split one-line OC messages

nl_oc_msg_args                            { False, True }   Whether to
put each OC message parameter on a separate line   See
nl_oc_msg_leave_one_liner
```

I don't think the formatter will actually move the parameters in the declaration to the new lines for you, the `align_oc_decl_colon` will only align them to colon if they already are in multiple lines.

Comment: Yep, looks like Uncrustify will not move the parameters to the new lines.
After all, I ended up using Clang-Format + Xcode syntax re-indent with BBUncrustifyPlugin. Works in a much more predictable way.